# Access Token and Refresh Token Dilema - JWT

Tags: node.js, api, security, authentication, jwt

I have a dilemma following the use of Access Token with Refresh Tokens.

Let's say we have the following scenarios:

1. User Login -> An **access token** valid for **5 minutes** is returned and saved in local storage. At the same time, a **refresh token** valid for **3 months** is saved in **cookies** with **httpOnly** and **secure** properties. The application will use the access token to get access to resources and after 5 minutes when it expires it will automatically use the refresh token to generate a new access token. After 3 months the user will be asked to log in again.
2. User Login -> An **access token** valid for **3 months** is saved in **cookies** with **httpOnly** and **secure** properties. The application will use this token to get access to resources and after 3 months the user will be asked to log in again.

What is the point in using method **1** instead of method **2**?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. If you can do #2, then you should, and it's more secure. JWTs are vastly overused, in case of #2, your access token is almost like a plain old session id, why not just use a session id then? (The only reason could be real statelessness, but in many cases the application is not stateless anyway, for example if you want to be able to revoke tokens.)

What you cannot do with #2 is sending the access token to a different origin, and that is actually needed sometimes. Imagine you app is hosted on example.com, but your api is exampleapi.com. If you stored your access token in a cookie, it could not be sent to the api. What usually happens in a more generic case is you have a refresh token (almost like a session, but without server-side state) with the identity provider that can issue tokens on idp.example.com, that's the domain of the secure, htponly cookie. This issues a jwt that your app downloaded from [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) can use on api.example.com or wherever else, because the access token is stored by javascript (eg. in localStorage). The point is the token can be accessed by javascript (xss), but it's short-lived, and xss requires user interaction, so it's not easy for an attacker to issue a new access token without the user doing something. The refresh token is stored more securely in a httponly cookie.

If you don't want to send your tokens to a different origin, a httponly cookie is actually better, and you're right, a refresh token doesn't make much sense then. Note though that if the token is stored in a cookie, you will have to mitigate csrf too.

Comment: Ok, thank you. This makes sense. But if we have another origin and at log in, we send both access token and refresh token. Where do we store them?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. In a single sign-on scenario the login server (identity provider) that issues the access token should have its own session or refresh token in a httponly cookie for its own domain, and then the issued token would typically be stored in localstorage so it can be used on application domains. Without single sign-on, this whole thing doesn't make a lot of sense, you just need a session, or a long-lived jwt stored in a httponly cookie (#2 above), if you accept the risks of jwts, long sessions, and the additional complexity associated with this solution.

Comment: Ok so from what you are saying I understand the following:

User Login -> A refresh token is saved in Redis, let's say as a key:value pair. The access token is send to the client which will be saved in local storage. If the access token is stolen, how can the refresh token be revoked?

Comment: Why do you need these separate tokens at all? Why do you actually need tokens? What's wrong with issuing a plain old session id and storing state server-side, will your solution really have such load that only a stateless solution could work? Even in that case why not just issue a jwt on login, send it to the client as a httponly cookie and that's it? In your case the whole complexity of a refresh token sounds unnecessary.

Comment: I was referring to the case when you have a different origin.

Comment: Also revoking tokens is basically the user logging out, in which case you would delete them from the client. For additional security, you could have a list of revoked tokens, maintained until their validity ends, but that compromises statelessness. You need to assess the risks.